# How can i add border infront of text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add border infront of text but i am not able to do that .
I have added the image , can anyone tell how i can complete this ?
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOyS.png)

I am trying to add border infront of text but border is getting added to whole div. I am trying to add border only infront of text.

Comment: That's quite doable, but you need to provide the relevant HTML and CSS showing what you've tried.

Comment: We cannot help sensibly without knowing your HTML structure and any relevant CSS as  you can see from the answers you are getting which are having to guess at what might help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which will help you put code into your question, otherwise it will shortly be closed for lack of detail.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The example above is from MDN Webdocs,[refereence link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

The `<fieldset>` element is used to group related elements in a form. The  element defines

a caption for the `<fieldset>` element and it will appear on the border of the `<fieldset>`.

This will render a box with the words "Text on Border" on the top border of the box. The  element provides this feature in conjunction with the `<fieldset>` element.

Comment: I tried to acheive this through fieldset but its adding border to all sides ,

Answer (score 0):

```css
#a {
  border: 4px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

#b {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.6em;
}

#c {
  display: inline-block;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id="a">

<div id="b">
Welcome to
</div>

<div id="c">
Momentto Caffe
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `::before` with white border.

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.a div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 20px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.a,
.a div {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>abc</div>
  <div>defgh</div>
</div>
```